# How do I know if the SmtpClient actually sent the email?

Tags: asynchronous, smtp, async-await, smtpclient, asp.net-identity-2

I am using .NET 4.5 and am trying to use the SmtpClient() SendMailAsync method. Sure there are LOTS of examples out there but many are just reposts of other person's code.

Basically I am trying to use an Email Service for Identity 2.x and therefore the method has this signature

```
public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message) { ... }
```

ultimately there it will have something like the next statement to send the mail asynchronously:

```
smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);
```

The thing is, I have multiple email servers in my configuration file and the idea is that if one of those fails the system should try the next until it is able to send the mail (I know it is no guarantee the mail has arrived anywhere). Something like this:

```
foreach (var oneSmtpServerInfo in FallbackSmtpServers)
{
     :
     smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);          // <--- successful? [A]
     :
}
```

but as you guess, if the 'A' statement is successful in processing the mail message I do not want to continue with the other servers in the list.

Comment: The only thing you can check for if the execution throws an exception. The exception will be thrown on the position where you add the await statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just `await` the async task like this:

```
foreach (var oneSmtpServerInfo in FallbackSmtpServers)
{
     :
     await smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);
     :
}
```